# Nilpotent Elements of a Group Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number and assume a group ring $R=KG$, where $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and $G$ is a finite $p$-group. I want to find the set of nilpotent elements of $R$.

Thanks for any leading answer!

Comment: For some arguments, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704679/show-that-the-group-ring-f-pg-where-g-is-a-p-group-has-a-unique-maximal.).

Comment: or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567318/prove-that-the-augmentation-ideal-in-the-group-ring-mathbbz-p-mathbbzg-is?noredirect=1&lq=1 for full answer

Comment: @xsnl Thanks for your comment, but I want the set of all nilpotent elements (which of course contains the augmentation ideal).

Comment: Elements outside of augmentation ideal map to nonzero elements of $K$, and (I think) that $K$ does not have any zero divisors, does it?

Comment: @xsnl When an element $\sum n_i$ of $K$ is nonzero, what does it have to do with an element, say, $\sum n_ig$ outside the augmentation ideal being non-nilpotent? I don't understand.

Comment: Augmentation $\epsilon$ is ring homomorphism, what is not obvious? Take any $x \in KG \, \setminus  ker \, \epsilon $, then $\epsilon(x) \in K^*$, particularly nonzero. For any natural $n$ $\epsilon(x^n) = \epsilon(x)^n$ — still nonzero and cannot be image of zero element.